# How to unload uiView with subview

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I am having tough time figuring out how to unload my UIView.

So Here is what I am doing.

I have a UI View class

```
@protocol JitsiViewDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
- (void)meetingEnded;
@end

@interface JitsiView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, nullable, weak) id<JitsiViewDelegate> delegate;
- (void)join:(JitsiMeetingConfig*)config;
@end
```

Where join (.m) file looks like this

```
- (void) join:(JitsiMeetingConfig*)config
{
    RCTBridge *bridge = [[Jitsi sharedInstance] getReactBridge];
  rootView = [[RNRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
                                moduleName: @"JitsiTest"
                              initialProperties: [self getInitialProperties:config]];
  rootView.backgroundColor = self.backgroundColor;
  // Add rootView as a subview which completely covers this one.
          [rootView setFrame:[self bounds]];
        rootView.autoresizingMask
            = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth
                | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [self addSubview:rootView];
}
```

In above

RNRootView is [this](https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/blob/master/ios/sdk/src/RNRootView.m)

and RCTBridge would be [this](https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/blob/master/ios/sdk/src/RCTBridgeWrapper.m)

I am using this in a swift project

```
import UIKit
import JitsiSdk;

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var videoButton: UIButton?
    fileprivate var JitsiView: jitsiView?
    fileprivate var config: JitsiMeetingConfig?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       //Config (removed code intentionally as it wasn't realvent) 

    }
    
    @IBAction func joinMeeting(_ sender: Any) {
                let jitsiView = JitsiView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.size.width, height:self.view.bounds.size.height ))
                .delegate = self
                self.jitsiView = jitsiView;
                self.view.addSubview(jitsiView)
                jitsiView.join(config);
    }
    
    fileprivate func onMeetingEnded() {
            if(jitsiView != nil) {
                jitsiView?.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
}


extension ViewController: JitsiViewDelegate {
    func meetingEnded() {
        onMeetingEnded()
    }
}
```

Here on meetingEnded, I want to remove `JitsiView` and show the content which were there in my view controller before loading `JitsiMeetView` but the current code is throwing following error

> 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Modifications to the
> layout engine must not be performed from a background thread after it
> has been accessed from the main thread.'

Can someone help me in understanding that why I am getting this error and how I can fix it?

Comment: I'm not really sure, but are you confusing delegates with view hierarchy? To start, why not simply `present` a view controller full screen that it's root view is `JitsiView`?, and then simply dismiss it? (You tagged this [iOS] so I'm assuming it's not something you are tryin to run on macOS.) Next, Why are you trying to add/remove views? Finally, the error actually suggests you are doing something UI-related from a background thread. That is a huge no-no.

Answer (score 0):

> Modifications to the layout engine must not be performed from a background thread after it has been accessed from the main thread.

This means that you are trying to call `onMeetingEnded()` on a background thread. All UI work must happen on main/UI thread.

Here's what you can do -

```
func meetingEnded() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
        self?.onMeetingEnded()
    }
}
```